# How to define direction for primary key / sorting columns in Clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to optimize a MergeTree table for queries that always have a `ORDER BY created_date DESC` clause. See schema below.

If I add `created_date` to the `ORDER BY` / `PRIMARY KEY` in the `CREATE TABLE` statement, I noticed that when `EXPLAIN`ing the query, there are `ReverseTransform` nodes. I'm assuming that this impacts query performance, because I assume column decompression requires reading in the same direction as compression.

I tried adding `DESC` to the `ORDER BY` clause when creating the table, but this does not work.

My questions:

- Is my assumption that this affects performance correct?
- If so, how to specify the sorting direction for a column in the `ORDER BY` of a `CREATE TABLE`?

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    `created_date` DateTime64(6, 'UTC') CODEC(Delta(8), ZSTD(1)),
    `type` LowCardinality,
    `stuff` String
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY (created_date, type);  -- NOTE: adding DESC doesn't work here
```

Answer (score 0):

In clickhouse
PRIMARY KEY use for o(log n) in-memory search
PRIMARY KEY is subset of sorting key
sorting key defined with ORDER BY clause

sorting key used for better compression when the same values of columns placed near each other

so DESC have no sense here

if you think `DESC` will allow not to use ORDER BY in SELECT queries, this is not guaranteed even for standard ORDER BY direction
because some parts of queries could be executed in parallel and send data to socket from different data parts

also look https://kb.altinity.com/engines/mergetree-table-engine-family/pick-keys/